# How to return portion of string from data that's not escaped in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm displaying my data as follows `{!! $post->content !!}` and it works as expected, but when I try to return a portion of the string by doing `{!! Str::substr($post->content, 0, 30) !!}` I don't get any string returned. I've tried different options but I can't seem to make it work. Kindly assist!

Answer (score 0):

since you'r in blade template, you probably need to add "->toHtmlString()" at the end, like this :

```
Str::substr($post->content, 0, 30)->toHtmlString()
```

i'll invite you to read [this part of laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-str-to-html-string)

Comment: That throws an error, ```Call to a member function toHtmlString() on string```

Comment: If you're on laravel 9 or 8,you need to cast the string with STR::of() before using  the method "toHtmlString()" , sry for the confusion, I rarely use helper on blade template